# Error: Router is not defined V0.7.0 Meteor 0.8.0

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have just update iron-router to the latest 0.7.0 and having errors.

Before updating I was using "dev" branch Blaze and everything worked fine.

I have the routes.js in the /lib/router.js so it can load first on both client and server. This is the error I get when I run mrt :

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.


/Users/pemmy/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
ReferenceError: Router is not defined
    at app/lib/routes.js:1:36
    at app/lib/routes.js:79:3
    at /Users/pemmy/projects/Meteor/projects/toonokio/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:155:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/pemmy/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /Users/pemmy/projects/Meteor/projects/toonokio/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

This is what I have on my router.js file:

```
1. Router.configure({
2. //    layoutTemplate: 'basicLayout',
3.     notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
4.     yieldTemplates: {
5. //        'header': { to: 'header' },
6. //        'footer': { to: 'footer' }
7.     }
8. });

79. Router.map(function () {
80.     this.route('home', {
81.         path :  '/',
82.         controller :  HomeController
83.     });
84. });
```

Any suggestions on what am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks,
Praney

Comment: Did you remove iron-router package and re-install again?

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had this error and the `iron-router` package was missing from my `.meteor/packages` file. Replaced it and did a `mrt install` and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

Tried `mrt install` and still had the problem.

`mrt add iron-router` solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this answer it may solve your issue:

[Meteor: App does not work on 0.9.1.1 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727318/meteor-app-does-not-work-on-0-9-1-1-version)

do `meteor remove iron-router` and after that `meteor add iron:router` which solved my problem. suggested by

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721887/565557