# Meteor - Many errors after update to v0.9.1

Tags: templates, meteor, undefined

I've been working on a Meteor project for a month then yesterday I was asked to update to the Meteor v0.9.1 version. After that, when I start my app using `meteor`, it throws a lot of error on the client-side console. Here they are:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function iron-dynamic-template.js:416
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined helpers.js:139
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function router.js:61
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'RouteController' of undefined global-imports.js:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.layout.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.header.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.404.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined meteor-streams.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: Router is not defined route.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined layout.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined header.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function about.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined chat_box.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined chat_rooms.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined user_profile.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined messages.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined rooms.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined utilities.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: TypingUsersStream is not defined main.js?ddb2df78e0fe11ef747b14020685864d14f8bd03:5
Uncaught ReferenceError: Spacebars is not defined login_buttons_dialogs.html:4
```

I have tried many ways but neither of them works.

Comment: do you have some relatives paths in your js files ?

Comment: no.. and when I ask one of my friend who has just updated to v0.9.1 today, he meets the same problem :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just solved my problem by removing the `iron-router` package then install the `iron:router` package.

Answer (score 0):

That is a known issue with 0.9.1, and a fix as been released by Meteor team. Updating to 0.9.1.1 should solve that.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/nYw4Vyae9rw