# Meteor: App does not work on 0.9.1.1 version

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Getting errors like

```
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Template.__create__')
    (anonymous function) (iron-dynamic-template.js, line 416)
    (anonymous function) (iron-dynamic-template.js, line 433)
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Parent.prototype')

[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Iron.Layout({template: this.options.layoutTemplate})')

[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Template

[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Template
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do `meteor remove iron-router` and after that `meteor add iron:router` which solved my problem.  suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721887/565557